# Java lambda method and new Object

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have the following code:

```
public class RefDemo {

    static class Demo implements Runnable {

        public Demo() {
            System.out.println(this.toString() + "-----");
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("run");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = Demo::new; // lambda ref constructor method
        runnable.run(); // does not do anything
        System.out.println(runnable);
        Runnable demo = new Demo(); // using new to create a Demo instance
        demo.run();
        System.out.println(demo);
    }
}
```

Which prints:

```
RefDemo$Demo@7291c18f----- // lambda run constructor method print
RefDemo$$Lambda$1/793589513@34a245ab // main method print
RefDemo$Demo@7cc355be-----
run
RefDemo$Demo@7cc355be
```

I don't know why the code does not print `run` when calling `runnable.run();`

Why does that happen?

Comment: `runnable.run()` calls the constructor, **not** the `run` method of `Demo`.

Comment: `new Demo()` and `Demo::new` are not equivalent.

Comment: try `runnable.run().run()`

Comment: the answer's [da-do-run().run()](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uTqnam1zgiw)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This code

```
Runnable runnable = Demo::new;
```

Is equivalent to this code

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override 
    public void run() {
        new Demo();
    }
};
```

So you are not referring to the `run` method of `Demo` but to the constructor.

Answer (score 20):

You are simply using `Runnable` in too many places and confusing yourself. The following code makes it a bit clearer what is happening:

```
public class RefDemo {

    static class Demo {

        public Demo() {
            System.out.println(this.toString() + "-----");
        }

        public void something() {
            System.out.println("something");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = Demo::new; 
        runnable.run();

        System.out.println(runnable);

        Demo demo = new Demo();
        demo.something();

        System.out.println(demo);
    }
}
```

`Runnable runnable = Demo::new;` means that you now have a reference to the constructor of `Demo` (which still works after dropping the conformance to the `Runnable` interface). And you store that reference in a variable of type `Runnable` which only works because their functional interfaces are compatible. Calling `run` on that reference then simply calls the constructor, **not** the `run` / `something` method of  `Demo`.

Comment: `Runnable runnable = Demo::new;  `this mean only using lambda create a virtual anon instances which implements `Runnable `interface, but why it can  print `RefDemo$Demo@7291c18f----- //lambda run constructor methods print`?

Comment: @lonecloud what if for the purpose of the example you re-write it like this `Runnable x = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Demo();
            }
        };` would that make more sense?

Comment: @lonecloud because you still end up calling the constructor, and inside the constructor `this` / `toString` still refers to a `Demo` instance. Printing the runnable itself however outputs the anonymous name of the lambda.

Answer (score 11):

The lines:

```
Runnable runnable = Demo::new;
runnable.run();
```

Are equivalent to:

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new Demo(); // Creates an instance of the Demo class, and nothing more
    }
};
runnable.run();
```

At the same time, your intention was to invoke the `run` method from the `Demo` class through a method reference. Therefore, I assume you meant the following:

```
Runnable runnable = new Demo()::run;
runnable.run();
// But, this is a little bit redundant...
```

The above code is equivalent to:

```
Demo demo = new Demo();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        demo.run();
    }
};
runnable.run();
```

**P.S.** You don't really need a method reference here, so just write:

```
new Demo().run();
```

Or:

```
Runnable demo = new Demo();
demo.run();
```

Answer (score 6):

`Demo::new` is the constructor of the `Demo` class. Since you assign it to a reference to the `Runnable` interface, calling `runnable.run()` invokes the constructor and creates a new `Demo` instance. The `run()` method is not executed.

If you want to define a `Runnable` instance that calls `Demo`'s `run()` method using a method reference, you can write:

```
Runnable runnable = new Demo()::run;
```

Of course, since `Demo` already implements `Runnable`, it's much simpler to just write:

```
Runnable runnable = new Demo();
```